# Hard sum with harmonics numbers

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

Prove or disprove that $S=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{H_n^{2}}~{H_n^{(2)}}+3{H_n^{(4)}}}{n~2^n}=\frac{25}{16}\zeta(5)+\frac{7}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$.

Comment: What is $\zeta$? Also what is $H_n^k$? harmonics numbers? wtf is that? Do you mean partial sums of the harmonic series? Or terms in it?

Comment: @Terrence Town: Unless indicated otherwise one should assume the standard notations:
$H_n\;$ are the harmonic numbers,  $H_n^{2}\;$ is the square of $H_n,\;$
$H_n^{(r)}$ are generalized harmonic numbers, $\zeta\;$ is the Riemann Zeta function. With this, it is a valid and clear statement, although no question (and no indication of own work).

Comment: where $H_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ is a harmonic number.
 and $H_n^{(2)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2} $

Comment: $H_n^{2} is the square of H_n$

Comment: from where did u get this?